# htaccess url rewrite issue

Tags: url, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm successfully rewriting a users profile page thusly:

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ /profile/profile.php?u=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/$ /profile/profile.php?u=$1 [NC]

so site.com/username was site.com/profile.php?u=username

Easy.

But now.. I'd like to have standard pages n folders like this...

site.com/login
site.com/help

etc... but the site thinks these are usernames... I've added rules to differentiate them but they dont seem to pick up - ie the one below doesnt work..

RewriteRule ^/login/twitter/$ /login/twitter/index.php [NC]

It thinks login is a username.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use conditional rewrites before your RewriteRule to skip over your reserved names  and files and folders that already exist on server:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/reserved1 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/reserved2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

REQUEST_URI is the resource requested in HTTP request line. The first two lines mean that the URI should not start with your reserved names and should skip over /reserved1 and /reserved2

REQUEST_FILENAME is the same as SCRIPT_FILENAME CGI variable and contains the full local filesystem path to the file or directory matching the request.
The last two lines mean to skip real files and directolries that already exist in server.